# stuck on decryption in new rail fence cipher (zig zac patten)

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography

i am tying to make new cipher which is similar to rail fence but in zic zac Patten for example

```
   *   * *   *
    * * * * *
     *     *
```

i success fully able to encrypt text with above patten.

here is a my code in javascript

```js
var plain_txt = "mynameismanan5439"

var a = ''
var b = ''
var c = ''
var d = ''
var flag_a = 0

function enc(plain) {
  for (var i = 0; i < plain.length; i = i + 4) {
    if (flag_a == 0) {
      a += plain.charAt(i)
      //console.log(i+","+(i+1)+","+(i+2)+","+(i+3))
      b += plain.charAt(i + 1)
      c += plain.charAt(i + 2)
      b += plain.charAt(i + 3)
      flag_a = 1
      continue
    } else {

      a += plain.charAt(i)
      b += plain.charAt(i + 1)

      //console.log(i+","+(i+1))
      i = i - 2
      flag_a = 0
    }
  }
  return (a + b + c)
}
console.log(enc(plain_txt))
```

but here my problem is that i didn't figure out that how to write decryption program of given problem please help me

i want output something like `dec(enc(plain_text))==plain_text`

thank you in advance

Comment: i am sure that it is successfully encrypted by paper work

Comment: 1. Why `continue`? 2. Where is your best effort try: [mcve] example of your decryption attempt.

Comment: But i didn't figured out that which logic use for reverse or for decryption it ia very complicated to reverse it please give me if any one have suggestions

Comment: can any one solve some other algorithm like this.

Answer (score 1):

Make some diagrams:

```
mynameismanan5439
abcbababcbababcba the order the letters are assigned to a, b, c

a: mminn9
b: yaesaa53
c: nm4

mminn9yaesaa53nm4 result
```

Now just go backwards

```
mminn9yaesaa53nm4

a: mminn9
b: yaesaa53
c: nm4

abcbababcbababcba
mynameismanan5439
```

The code handles six characters at a time in the order `abcbab`, two `a`s, one `c`, and three `b`s. So you can know for 99 characters there are 16 full sequences 6*16 = 96 and an additional 4 characters. The final 4 characters must be "abcb" so there are 32:'a', 48:'b' , 16:'c'. Add the characters from the final block and you get 33 'a', 50:'b' 17:'c'. now breakup the 'a', 'b' and 'c's. The catch any why this is not a good cipher is that the full length must be known to separate the characters for decryption.

A modulus 6 operation on the total length will provide the number of character in the last block. Then 1/3 = 'a's, 1/6 = 'c's and 1/2 = "b"s.

Here is a simplification of the OP's answer in creating the decipher a, b & c strings.

```js
function dec(cipher){
var plain = ''
var a =''
var b =''
var c =''

// -- begin simplification --
var length = cipher.length
var lastChunkLength = length%6
var chunkSize = (length-lastChunkLength)/6

console.log("lastChunkLength: " + lastChunkLength)
console.log("chunkSize:       " + chunkSize)

var aLength = chunkSize * 2
var bLength = chunkSize * 3
var cLength = chunkSize * 1

if(lastChunkLength>0){
  aLength += 1
}
if(lastChunkLength>1){
  bLength += 1
}
if(lastChunkLength>2){
  cLength += 1
}
if(lastChunkLength>3){
  bLength += 1
}
if(lastChunkLength>4){
  aLength += 1
}

a = cipher.slice(0, aLength);
b = cipher.slice(aLength, aLength+bLength);
c = cipher.slice(aLength+bLength, aLength+bLength+cLength);
// -- end simplification --

var a_counter = 0
var b_counter = 0
var c_counter = 0

for(var i = 0;i<length-1;i+=6){
plain += a.charAt(a_counter) + b.charAt(b_counter) + c.charAt(c_counter)+b.charAt(b_counter+1)+a.charAt(a_counter+1)+b.charAt(b_counter+2);
a_counter+=2;
b_counter+=3;
c_counter++;
}
if((length % 6)==1){
    plain += a.charAt(a_counter) ;
  }
  else if((length % 6)==2){
    plain += a.charAt(a_counter) + b.charAt(b_counter);
  }
  else if((length % 6)==3){
    plain += a.charAt(a_counter) + b.charAt(b_counter) + c.charAt(c_counter);
  }
  else if((length % 6)==4){
    plain += a.charAt(a_counter) + b.charAt(b_counter) + c.charAt(c_counter)+b.charAt(b_counter+1);
  }
  else if((length % 6)==5){
    plain += a.charAt(a_counter) + b.charAt(b_counter) + c.charAt(c_counter)+b.charAt(b_counter+1)+a.charAt(a_counter+1);
  }                                                                                           
return plain;
}

var cipher = "mminn9yaesaa53nm4"
console.log("cipher: " + cipher)

var deCipher = dec(cipher);
console.log("decryption is = " + deCipher)
```

Comment: Exactly i stuck here that how to divide in three part as in your example you divided in a,b,c what if some enter different string example if i will enter 100 character of string on that time end of Patten is different then 99 char of string

Comment: Thanks for your time can you got any mathematical equation for dividing nth length of string in to 3 part a,b,c as per your explanation

 in my code length of string is matter

Comment: here i got a solution thanks for your logic which is "abcbab" Patten ;-)

Answer (score 1):

@zaph maybe three is onother way to find out by the way i appreciate your answers
and finally i found a solution thanks @zaph for motivation and your time for giving me a tips and please remove **The catch any why this is not a good cipher is that the full length must be known to separate the characters for decryption.** from your comment because nothing is impossible

here is a code with decryption as i want

```js
var plain_txt = "mynameismanan5439"


function enc(plain){
  var a = ''
  var b = ''
  var c = ''
  var d =''
  var flag_a = 0
for(var i = 0;i<plain.length;i=i+4){
    if(flag_a == 0){
    a += plain.charAt(i)
   //console.log(i+","+(i+1)+","+(i+2)+","+(i+3))
    b += plain.charAt(i+1)
    c += plain.charAt(i+2)
    b += plain.charAt(i+3)
    flag_a = 1
    continue
    }

    else{

        a += plain.charAt(i)
        b += plain.charAt(i+1)

    //console.log(i+","+(i+1))
        i = i-2
        flag_a = 0
    }
}
return (a+b+c)
}
console.log("encryption is = "+enc(plain_txt))
function dec(cipher){
var plain = ''
var a =''
var b =''
var c =''
var length = cipher.length
var multply = parseInt(length/6)
if (length>=6){
a = cipher.slice(0, (2*multply));
b = cipher.slice((2*multply),(5*multply));
c = cipher.slice((5*multply));
}
if((length%6)==1){
  a =  cipher.slice(0, (2*multply)+1);
  b = cipher.slice((2*multply)+1,(5*multply)+1);
  c = cipher.slice((5*multply)+1);
}
else if((length%6)==2){
  a =  cipher.slice(0, (2*multply)+1);
  b = cipher.slice((2*multply)+1,(5*multply)+2);
  c = cipher.slice((5*multply)+3);
}

else if((length%6)==3){
  a =  cipher.slice(0, (2*multply)+1);
  b = cipher.slice((2*multply)+1,(5*multply)+2);
  c = cipher.slice((5*multply)+2);
}
else if((length%6)==4){
  a =  cipher.slice(0, (2*multply)+1);
  b = cipher.slice((2*multply)+1,(5*multply)+3);
  c = cipher.slice((5*multply)+3);
}
else if((length%6)==5){
  a =  cipher.slice(0, (2*multply)+2);
  b = cipher.slice((2*multply)+2,(5*multply)+4);
  c = cipher.slice((5*multply)+4);
}
var a_counter = 0
var b_counter = 0
var c_counter = 0

for(var i = 0;i<length-1;i+=6){
plain += a.charAt(a_counter) + b.charAt(b_counter) + c.charAt(c_counter)+b.charAt(b_counter+1)+a.charAt(a_counter+1)+b.charAt(b_counter+2);
a_counter+=2;
b_counter+=3;
c_counter++;
}
if((length % 6)==1){
    plain += a.charAt(a_counter) ;
  }
  else if((length % 6)==2){
    plain += a.charAt(a_counter) + b.charAt(b_counter);
  }
  else if((length % 6)==3){
    plain += a.charAt(a_counter) + b.charAt(b_counter) + c.charAt(c_counter);
  }
  else if((length % 6)==4){
    plain += a.charAt(a_counter) + b.charAt(b_counter) + c.charAt(c_counter)+b.charAt(b_counter+1);
  }
  else if((length % 6)==5){
    plain += a.charAt(a_counter) + b.charAt(b_counter) + c.charAt(c_counter)+b.charAt(b_counter+1)+a.charAt(a_counter+1);
  }                                                                                           
return plain;
}

console.log("decryption is = "+dec(enc(plain_txt)))
```

tell if you have any idea about optimizing code 
thank you

Comment: Maybe still there is a different way. But it is a more effective it decreases loop iterations by -6. but still if you find some new things then ping .